# Actual Custom Nodes in Godot

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot-4, plugin

So I am creating a plugin for Godot 4, and I want to create an actual custom node.
What do I mean by that?

First to create a custom node I do:

```
@tool
extends CharacterBody2D
class_name Player2D
```

But the problem is, when adding the node, it keeps the same script. Easy fix though, create a new node to be added.

```
@tool
extends Player2D
class_name NewPlayer2D
```

but now we have a problem. It still keeps the same script. How do I create a node that I can add, that automatically starts with

```
extends Player2D
```

for me to use?

Comment: What do you mean by "it keeps the same script"?

Comment: @DMGregory when I add a new Player2D node, it already contains a script with the example code I shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make an script like this:

```
@tool
extends CharacterBody2D
class_name Player2D
```

Then you can add a `CharacterBody2D` to your scene, give it an script, and it is write this:

```
extends Player2D
```

And it should work. *You might need to add `@tool` to it, depending on what you want it to do.*

*This has pushed me to make my scripts more reusable. As I often need to consider how to extend them other than adding an script to them. Some times that means creating nodes that expect to be placed as children of a node of an specific type. In other cases it means having a node interact with their children, or adding custom signals, or export nodes variables.*

---

If you were to add the custom class via en [`EditoPlugin`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/plugins/editor/index.html) with the now discouraged API [`add_custom_type`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_editorplugin.html#class-editorplugin-method-add-custom-type) instead of using `class_name` what you would gain is Godot preventing you from *removing* the script, and avoding a bit of namespace pollution. *Which for me be too little gain for the hassle, as `EditorPlugin`s also need to be enabled in the editor.*

However, I want to note that if you need custom behavior **in the editor**, you could create an `EditorPlugin` that handles your nodes (for your case it could handle `CharacterBody2D` for example), so the extra logic you need is not on a base class. *While the `EditorPlugin` won't execute in runtime, it can manipulate the scene in the editor, for example automatically adding other nodes with their own scripts, which would execute in runtime.*

---

However, it seems you want to be able to add a `Player2D` to the scene and have it appear without an script... In that case the `Player2D` class must not be an script. Which at the time of writing means to either:

- Adding the class as part of a [module](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/contributing/development/core_and_modules/custom_modules_in_cpp.html) to the source code and [recompiling](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/contributing/development/compiling/index.html).
- Adding the class via [GDExtension](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdextension/index.html).

This would also allow you to avoid overload from the GDScript runtime. Which makes it a good idea for performance critical code once other avenues of optimization have been exhausted. Also since it is less attractive for quick prototyping, the usual advice is to design what you want with GDScript and then port it.

Comment: Thank you very much for this response! This helps a lot. I will use this. Thank you!!